# How do I get the instantiated type of a class in Swift?

Tags: swift, types

I'm a C# programmer trying to get my head around Swift's type system. The code below defines a super class *fruit* with an accessor *getTypeOfFruit()*. I would like it to return the instantiated type and not the superclass's type.

ASIDE: Is there any advanced documentation on Swift's type system? Most of what I've encountered only covers the basics.

```
public class Fruit {
    private var fruitType = Fruit.Type.self      // generic fruit type
    public func getTypeOfFruit<T>() -> T.Type  { 
        return fruitType as! T.Type              //
    }
}

public class Apple: Fruit { 

}

public class TimApple: Apple {
}

var fruit = Fruit.self        // error:  Instance member 'getTypeOfFruit' cannot be used
print(fruit.getTypeOfFruit()) // should print "Fruit"

var fruit = Apple.self
print(fruit.getTypeOfFruit()) // should print "Apple"

fruit = TimApple.self
print(fruit.getTypeOfFruit()) // should print "TimApple"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`type(of:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/2885064-type/), e.g.,

```swift
public class Fruit {
    public func getTypeOfFruit() -> Fruit.Type  {
        return type(of: self)
    }
}

public class Apple: Fruit { }

public class TimApple: Apple { }

var fruit = Fruit()
print(fruit.getTypeOfFruit()) // prints "Fruit"

fruit = Apple()
print(fruit.getTypeOfFruit()) // prints "Apple"

fruit = TimApple()
print(fruit.getTypeOfFruit()) // print "TimApple"
```

Comment: I'm digging this swift language stuff. Apple always gets it right. I'm wondering if it makes sense to have the accessor when it's easy enough to call type(). Do you know of some deeper level literature covering Swift's type system. It seems to have an F# like type algebra. It's too bad C# didn't pick up some of this.

Comment: Does it make sense to have method, `getTypeOfFruit`? As you noted, `type(of:)` is simple enough. Or, better, rather than relying on [reflection](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/swift_standard_library/debugging_and_reflection) at all, for most use-cases, the native type checking/casting is more natural (e.g., `if fruit is TimApple { … }` or `switch fruit { case let tim as TimApple: … }`, etc.). Reflection is more of a debugging pattern, and in production code, there are often better approaches.

Comment: Re docs on type system, nothing in particular is leaping to mind other than Apple’s [Resources page](https://developer.apple.com/swift/resources/).

Comment: OK can I still store the type in a var and compare it without using reflection? Ie. how do I set fruit to contain the type only.

Comment: I’d be careful about storing the type and comparing it later. E.g. If you have another subclass, `class GreenApple: Apple { }`. Now you save its `type(of:)`. A test of `if greenApple is Apple { … }` works, but a test like `if greenAppleType == Apple.self { … }` doesn’t. A green apple is an apple and is a fruit. Generally you want type checking to honor the inheritance (e.g. “is kind of”, including subclasses) rather than looking for a particular instance (e.g. “is member of”, excluding subclasses). E.g. `if greenAppleType is Apple.Type { … }`.

Comment: Besides, we’re dealing with reference types, so passing a reference to the object and then testing types with Swift’s native `is` and `as` type checking (e.g. `if greenApple is Apple { … }`) is just as efficient, without resorting to metadata sort of pattern. And now that we increasingly use POP rather than OOP, it’s a bit moot, anyways.

Comment: All that having been said, if you *really* want to use `type(of:)`, feel free. I personally view it as more of a [debugging](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/swift_standard_library/debugging_and_reflection) feature than something that I’d use in production code, but if it really is the best way to solve your particular problem, then go ahead and use it.